# Grafana - Alert based on a minimum of requests

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux

I hope you can help me.
What I have is some metric data I am collecting. I want to send out an alert, when I reach a specific error-rate on these metrics.

To make clear, my data looks something like this:

- Timestamp
- value (the runtime of a query)
- state (error, success)
- api-endpoint called

I have a grafana-Board doing some calculations, drops out something linke this:

- error-rate
- api-endpoint
- number of calls made to the api endpoint

Fine for now - as I can read out on my grafana, I am able to send some error-messages/warnings, if the error-rate is too high. Works like a charm. But now comes the point:
If the first two (e.g.) calls to a specific api fail, I will instantly receive an alarm send by my grafana. I do not wan't that!

Is it possible - and if: how? - to alert me ONLY if this specific request was executed at least 5 times? It is no problem if this is a generic alert like "hey, something is wrong!" - but I need to figure out if the request triggering the alarm with 50-100% error-Rate was at least executed a specific amount of time before alarming.
It has to be done based on tags/fields, I do not want to add a single query for all of my 35+ APIs (number growing).

Any Idea anybody?

Using Grafana 8.0
Using InfluxDb 1.8 (with Flux enabled)

Answer (score 1):

Just to make clear, if everyone ever want's to do the same: FluxQL is king - you can use filter functionality in there and only base data on datasets where value count is greater than X.
Yes: FluxQL is damn hot. I love it since a few month.